# Populating form textarea value from array

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4.2, populate

I have a simple form. The returning json value from the server like below:

```
{
"success":true,
"data":{
    "DNR_ID":"9",
    "DNR_TYPE_ID":"1",
    "DNR_DEF_ID":"1",
    "DNR_DESC":"PROCTOR & GAMBLE HAFTASONU AKSIYONU",
    "STORES": {
        "0" => "ANKARA"
        "1" => "ISTANBUL"
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, there is an array inside the `data` which is `STORES`. So, what I want to do, put those values into textarea that available in the form.

The ExtJS simple form mechanism didn't work.

```
listeners: {
    select: function() {
        if (this.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
            var row = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];

            Ext.getCmp('dnr-list-info').getForm().load({
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>/list/get_dnr_info',
                params: {dnrid: row.get('DNR_ID')},
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    // In fact, this line doesn't necessary because form load function automatically fill the form
                    Ext.getCmp('dnr-list-info').getForm().setValues(res);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go `down` to the textarea component and `setValue` there.

```
myForm.down('#itemIdForTextArea').setValue('myValue');
```

or you can directly query the textarea by item id as well...

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemIdForTextArea')[0].setValue('myValue');
```

or id..

```
Ext.getCmp('idForTextArea').setValue('myValue');
```

More info available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-method-setValue)

Comment: Also if you are trying to load the form with data from the record.  You could use loadRecord.  Just make sure that the name on the textarea corresponds to the name in the store.